# Why does a webpack generated JS bundle complains about lack of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-2

I use jQuery in my script and added a `require` in my `entry` file (defined in `webpack.config.js`). I tried each of these imports:

```
import 'jquery'
var $ = require("jquery")
import $ from 'jquery'
```

The compilation shows that it is indeed included:

```
D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog>webpack
Hash: 3a4538db28bec4591dd8
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 3088ms
   Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
build.js  562 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   [0] ./webpack/js/explorer.js 1.37 kB {0} [built]
   [1] ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js 484 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 268 kB {0} [built]
(...)
```

When running my script in a browser, I get however on the console an error message:

```
build.js:20018 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:20018)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:129)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:17585)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:20)
    at Vue.el (build.js:66)
    at build.js:69
(anonymous) @ build.js:20018
__webpack_require__ @ build.js:20
(anonymous) @ build.js:129
__webpack_require__ @ build.js:20
(anonymous) @ build.js:17585
__webpack_require__ @ build.js:20
Vue.el @ build.js:66
(anonymous) @ build.js:69
```

**What does this error mean?**

I then stumbled upon [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43706479/903011) (without answers) which has a similar issue and tried to subsequently modify my files by adding to `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: "jquery",
       'window.jQuery': "jquery",
       'jQuery': "jquery"
    })
```

and a plain

```
import 'jquery'
```

in my entry file.

The issue stays the same.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery should not be in included *before* explorer.js and npm.js?

Comment: @BramVanroy: it should, but it is the first line in my entry file (`explorer.js` is imported a few lines below). Is the output of the compilation an indication about actual order of the files?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not a webpack guy. It just seemed odd that it was 'built' last. Maybe someone  else can help.